# How to get faster pairwise distance and vector calculations in Julia 0.5 compared to Matlab2016b?

Tags: matlab, performance, julia

I am running a program that requires repeated use of pairwise distance calculations across a collection of points in 2D and then calculating the vectors. This ends up causing a bottleneck in my run times so I have tried to re-write my code from Matlab to Julia to take advantage of its faster speeds. The problem I have run into, however, is that the function I have written in Julia is actually running five times slower than my Matlab implementation. Given Julia's reputation as being a substantially faster language, I am assuming that I have done something wrong.

I wrote a simple example to illustrate what I am seeing.

Julia code:

```
using Distances
function foo()
  historyarray = zeros(5000,150,2)
  a = randn(150,2)
  for i in 1:5000
    pd = pairwise(Euclidean(),a.')
    xgv = broadcast(-,a[:,1].',a[:,1])
    ygv = broadcast(-,a[:,2].',a[:,2])
    th = atan2(ygv,xgv)
    fv = 1./(pd+1)
    xfv = fv*cos(th)
    yfv = fv*sin(th)
    a[:,1]+= sum(xfv,2)
    a[:,2]+= sum(yfv,2)

    historyarray[i,:,:] = copy(a)
  end
end
```

Matlab code:

```
function foo
histarray = zeros(5000,150,2);
a = randn(150,2);
for i=1:5000

    pd = pdist2(a,a);
    xgv = -bsxfun(@minus,a(:,1),a(:,1)');
    ygv = -bsxfun(@minus,a(:,2),a(:,2)');
    th = atan2(ygv,xgv);
    fv = 1./(pd+1);
    xfv = fv.*cos(th);
    yfv = fv.*sin(th);
    a(:,1) = a(:,1)+sum(xfv,2);
    a(:,2) = a(:,2)+sum(yfv,2);

    histarray(i,:,:)=a;
end
```

end

When I test the Julia code's speed (multiple times to account for compiling time) I get:

```
@time foo()
16.110077 seconds (2.65 M allocations: 8.566 GB, 6.30% gc time)
```

The Matlab function's performance on the other hand is:

```
tic
foo
toc
Elapsed time is 3.339807 seconds.
```

When I have run the profile viewer on the Julia code the component that takes the most amount of time are lines 9, 11, and 12. Is there perhaps something strange happening with trigonometric functions?

Comment: You can use `pairwise` from [VectorizedRoutines.jl](https://github.com/ChrisRackauckas/VectorizedRoutines.jl). It should do well here. I think you may currently need master for it.

Comment: you can preallocate the temporary arrays & re-use them?

Comment: Your example code is a bit confusing. Are you running the loop 5000 iterations to get timing information, or is there some other reason? I'm asking because if you really want to run many iterations, it would be beneficial to pre-allocate all the arrays, and reuse them with in-place operations, or in fact, lift most of the calculations out of the loop.

Comment: @DNF Sorry for the confusion, this example code is just a cartoon version of what I am working on. In the actual code I am implementing the Runge–Kutta method for simulating dynamic forces across objects, so each iteration is a small delta-t in the evolution of the system.

Comment: One typical mistake you're making is writing Matlab code in Julia. The allocations are through the roof, and should easily be reduced by a factor of 1000 by avoiding temporary arrays. I did try to write that code, but I could not replicate your actual results, and the runtime was only a roughly 2x as fast, to my astonishment. Other than that, Matlab is probably beating Julia by using multithreading, which is something you can activate in Julia too, but which is experimental.

Comment: BTW the code as it stands, includes a force in the X-axis direction due to self interaction (an artifact of cos(0.0)=1.0 and `pd` calculated with a 1.0 increment to denominator). Is this desired? Or is the code just demonstrational?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea behind the get-rid-of-trig refactor is `sin(atan(x,y))==y/sqrt(x^2+y^2)`. Conveniently the function `hypot` calculates the square root denominator. `inv` is used to get away from slow divisions. The code:

```
# a constant input matrix to allow foo2/foo3 comparison
a = randn(150,2)

# calculation using trig functions
function foo2(b,n)
  a = copy(b)
  historyarray = zeros(n,size(a,1),2)
  pd = zeros(size(a,1), size(a,1))
  xgv = similar(pd)
  ygv = similar(pd)
  th = similar(pd)
  fv = similar(pd)
  xfv = similar(pd)
  yfv = similar(pd)
  tmp = zeros(size(a,1))
  @views for i in 1:n
      pairwise!(pd, Euclidean(),a.')
      xgv .= a[:,1].' .- a[:,1]
      ygv .= a[:,2].' .- a[:,2]
      th .= atan2.(ygv,xgv)
      fv .= 1./(pd.+1)
      xfv .= fv.*cos.(th)
      yfv .= fv.*sin.(th)
      a[:,1:1] .+= sum!(tmp, xfv)
      a[:,2:2] .+= sum!(tmp, yfv)
      historyarray[i,:,:] = a
  end
end

# helper function to handle annoying Infs from self interaction calc
nantoone(x) = ifelse(isnan(x),1.0,x)
nantozero(x) = ifelse(isnan(x),0.0,x)

# calculations using Pythagoras
function foo3(b,n)
  a = copy(b)
  historyarray = zeros(5000,size(a,1),2)
  pd = zeros(size(a,1), size(a,1))
  xgv = similar(pd)
  ygv = similar(pd)
  th = similar(pd)
  fv = similar(pd)
  xfv = similar(pd)
  yfv = similar(pd)
  tmp = zeros(size(a,1))
  @views for i in 1:n
      pairwise!(pd, Euclidean(),a.')
      xgv .= a[:,1].' .- a[:,1]
      ygv .= a[:,2].' .- a[:,2]
      th .= inv.(hypot.(ygv,xgv))
      fv .= inv.(pd.+1)
      xfv .= nantoone.(fv.*xgv.*th)
      yfv .= nantozero.(fv.*ygv.*th)
      a[:,1:1] .+= sum!(tmp, xfv)
      a[:,2:2] .+= sum!(tmp, yfv)
      historyarray[i,:,:] = a
  end
end
```

And a benchamrk:

```
julia> @time foo2(a,5000)
  9.698825 seconds (809.51 k allocations: 67.880 MiB, 0.33% gc time)

julia> @time foo3(a,5000)
  2.207108 seconds (809.51 k allocations: 67.880 MiB, 1.15% gc time)
```

A **>4x** improvement.

Another takeaway from this is the convenience of a NaN-to-something function which could be added to Base (similar to `coalesce` and `nvl` from SQL world).

Comment: When I run this code I get approximately the same speed as the matlab implementation. Well done! Maybe I am crazy, I just find it very strange that trig functions are such a problem. It seems to me that I should maybe hold off on Julia until the language is developed further before plunging in with more complicated projects.

Comment: Apart from trying to be a better scientific language, Julia wants to be a free language. Matlab is definitely not free. This creates some areas where vanilla Julia may be a step behind, such as the trig functions. But already Julia compiles with Intel's MKL (Math Kernel Library) to get better math performance. The license of MKL changes once in a while (it is still free to play with), but before giving up on Julia it would be best to try it. It also has better performance on many other math/linear algebra functions. If developing in Julia feels comfortable, performance shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 6):

You are correct that the calls to `sin`, `cos`, and `atan2` are the bottleneck in your Julia code. Nevertheless, the high number of allocations implies that there is still potential for optimizations.

On the upcoming version of Julia, your code can easily be rewritten to avoid unnecessary allocations by using the improved dot broadcasting syntax `a .= f.(b,c)`. This is equivalent to `broadcast!(f, a, b, c)` and updates `a` in place. Additionally, several dot broadcast calls on the rhs are automatically fused into a single one. Finally, the `@views` macro turns all slicing operations like `a[:,1]`, which makes a copy, into views. The new code looks like:

```
function foo2()
    a = rand(150,2)
    historyarray = zeros(5000,150,2)
    pd = zeros(size(a,1), size(a,1))
    xgv = similar(pd)
    ygv = similar(pd)
    th = similar(pd)
    fv = similar(pd)
    xfv = similar(pd)
    yfv = similar(pd)
    tmp = zeros(size(a,1))
    @views for i in 1:5000
        pairwise!(pd, Euclidean(),a.')
        xgv .= a[:,1].' .- a[:,1]
        ygv .= a[:,2].' .- a[:,2]
        th .= atan2.(ygv,xgv)
        fv .= 1./(pd.+1)
        xfv .= fv.*cos.(th)
        yfv .= fv.*sin.(th)
        a[:,1:1] .+= sum!(tmp, xfv)
        a[:,2:2] .+= sum!(tmp, yfv)
        historyarray[i,:,:] = a
    end
end
```

(I use element-wise multiplication in `xfv .= fv.*cos.(th)` like in your Matlab code instead of matrix multiplication.)

Benchmarking the new code shows a strong reduction in allocated memory:

```
julia> @benchmark foo2()
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  67.88 MiB
  allocs estimate:  809507
  --------------
  minimum time:     7.655 s (0.06% GC)
  median time:      7.655 s (0.06% GC)
  mean time:        7.655 s (0.06% GC)
  maximum time:     7.655 s (0.06% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          1
  evals/sample:     1
  time tolerance:   5.00%
  memory tolerance: 1.00%
```

(Most of this can be achieved on 0.5, but requires a bit more typing)

However, this still takes twice as long as your Matlab version. Profiling reveals that indeed most of the time is spent in the trigonometric functions.

Just for fun I tried:

```
const atan2 = +
const cos = x->2x
const sin = x->2x
```

and got:

```
julia> @benchmark foo2()
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
  memory estimate:  67.88 MiB
  allocs estimate:  809507
  --------------
  minimum time:     1.020 s (0.69% GC)
  median time:      1.028 s (0.68% GC)
  mean time:        1.043 s (2.10% GC)
  maximum time:     1.100 s (7.75% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          5
  evals/sample:     1
  time tolerance:   5.00%
  memory tolerance: 1.00%
```

I guess, one reason for the slowness of the trigonometric functions might be that I use the prebuilt binary and no self-compiled version of the `libm` library, which is used by Julia. Therefore, the `libm` code is not optimized for my processor. But I doubt that this will make Julia much faster than Matlab in this case. The Matlab code just seems to be already close to optimal for this algorithm.

Comment: Interesting, since a for loop is involved, I was definitely not expecting Matlab to be close to optimal. I downloaded the Julia 0.6 pre-release and ran your code, and indeed I see much more reasonable memory usage but a time about 2-3x slower than Matlab. However, if I recall correctly, many of Matlab's built-in functions do multi-threading by default. Is this where the discrepancy occurs? I am also very surprised that the trigonometric functions are notably slower than the pairwise distance calculation. Is the conclusion we have arrived to, at least for now, that I should stick with Matlab?

Comment: The overhead of for loops in Matlab does not matter in this case as most of the time is spent in optimized vectorized function calls (which might use multiple threads). Even with an overhead of the order of 1µs per iteration, the resulting 5ms slowdown would be completely negligible. Julia shines when one wants to implement an algorithm that is difficult or even impossible to express in a vectorized form. Fast custom types, multiple dispatch, and advanced metaprogramming can be very helpful as well.

Comment: A little math refactoring can get the >4x improvement of going from trig functions to more friendly functions. The new code is in another answer (too long for comment)

Answer (score 4):

I'm able to get a speed up vs matlab using multi threads on julia 0.5.

On my machine (i5 with 4 cores) I get the following times:
matlab R2012a - 8.5 seconds
julia 0.5 single thread - foo3() (see below) - 18.5 seconds
julia 0.5 multi threads - foo4() (see below) - 4.5 seconds

I.e. I'm able to get the julia single threaded function running twice as slow as matlab but a multi threaded function running twice as fast as matlab.

Apologies for this being a very verbose answer - thought it better to be comprehensive. I'm posting below each of the inner functions used as well as the main ones - foo3() and foo(4).

**1. Single Thread:**

The aim of the devectorised functions below were to avoid unnecessary memory allocations and to make use of the symmetry of the arrays. From tim's answer it looks like much of this can be handled with single lines in 0.6 with the dot notation.

```
function pdist2!(pd, a)
    m = size(a, 1)
    for col in 1:m
        for row in (col + 1):m
            s = 0.0
            for i in 1:2
                @inbounds s += abs2(a[col, i] - a[row, i])
            end
            @inbounds pd[row, col] = pd[col, row] = sqrt(s)
        end
    end
end

function dotminustranspose!(xgv, ygv, a)
    m = size(a, 1)
    for col in 1:m
        @inbounds for row in (col + 1):m
            xgv[row, col] = a[col, 1] - a[row, 1]
            ygv[row, col] = a[col, 2] - a[row, 2]
            xgv[col, row] = - xgv[row, col]
            ygv[col, row] = - ygv[row, col]
        end
    end
end

function atan2!(th, ygv, xgv)
    for i in eachindex(ygv)
        @inbounds th[i] = atan2(ygv[i], xgv[i])
    end
end

function invpdp1!(fv, pd)
    for i in eachindex(pd)
        @inbounds fv[i] = 1 / (pd[i] + 1)
    end
end

function fv_times_cos_th!(xfv, fv, th)
    for i in eachindex(th)
        @inbounds xfv[i] = fv[i] * cos(th[i])
    end
end

function fv_times_sin_th!(yfv, fv, th)
    for i in eachindex(th)
        @inbounds yfv[i] = fv[i] * sin(th[i])
    end
end

function adsum2!(a, xfv, yfv)
    n = size(a, 1)
    for j in 1:n
        for i in 1:n
            @inbounds a[i, 1] += xfv[i, j]
            @inbounds a[i, 2] += yfv[i, j]
        end
    end
end

function foo3()
    a = reshape(sin(1:300), 150, 2)
    histarray = zeros(5000, 150, 2)
    pd = zeros(size(a, 1), size(a, 1))
    xgv = zeros(pd)
    ygv = zeros(pd)
    th = zeros(pd)
    fv = zeros(pd)
    xfv = zeros(pd)
    yfv = zeros(pd)
    for i in 1:5000
        pdist2!(pd, a)
        dotminustranspose!(xgv, ygv, a)
        atan2!(th, ygv, xgv)
        invpdp1!(fv, pd)
        fv_times_cos_th!(xfv, fv, th)
        fv_times_sin_th!(yfv, fv, th)
        adsum2!(a, xfv, yfv)

        histarray[i, :, :] = view(a, :)
    end
    return histarray
end
```

Time:

```
@time histarray = foo3()
17.966093 seconds (24.51 k allocations: 13.404 MB)
```

**1. Multi Thread:**

The elementwise trig functions can be multithreaded using the `@threads` macro. And this gives me about a 4 x speedup. This is still experimental but I tested the outputs and they are identical.

```
using Base.Threads

function atan2_mt!(th, ygv, xgv)
    @threads for i in eachindex(ygv)
        @inbounds th[i] = atan2(ygv[i], xgv[i])
    end
end

function fv_times_cos_th_mt!(xfv, fv, th)
    @threads for i in eachindex(th)
        @inbounds xfv[i] = fv[i] * cos(th[i])
    end
end

function fv_times_sin_th_mt!(yfv, fv, th)
    @threads for i in eachindex(th)
        @inbounds yfv[i] = fv[i] * sin(th[i])
    end
end

function foo4()
    a = reshape(sin(1:300), 150, 2)
    histarray = zeros(5000, 150, 2)
    pd = zeros(size(a, 1), size(a, 1))
    xgv = zeros(pd)
    ygv = zeros(pd)
    th = zeros(pd)
    fv = zeros(pd)
    xfv = zeros(pd)
    yfv = zeros(pd)
    for i in 1:5000
        pdist2!(pd, a)
        dotminustranspose!(xgv, ygv, a)
        atan2_mt!(th, ygv, xgv)
        invpdp1!(fv, pd)
        fv_times_cos_th_mt!(xfv, fv, th)
        fv_times_sin_th_mt!(yfv, fv, th)
        adsum2!(a, xfv, yfv)

        histarray[i, :, :] = view(a, :)
    end
    return histarray
end
```

Time:

```
@time histarray = foo4()
4.569416 seconds (54.51 k allocations: 14.320 MB, 0.20% gc time)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use dot notation in order to broadcast some of the operations. Look at `foo2()` function.

```
using Distances
function foo1()
  historyarray = zeros(5000,150,2)
  a = randn(150,2)
  for i in 1:5000
    pd = pairwise(Euclidean(),a.')
    xgv = broadcast(-,a[:,1].',a[:,1])
    ygv = broadcast(-,a[:,2].',a[:,2])
    th = atan2(ygv,xgv)
    fv = 1./(pd+1)
    xfv = fv*cos(th)
    yfv = fv*sin(th)
    a[:,1]+= sum(xfv,2)
    a[:,2]+= sum(yfv,2)

    historyarray[i,:,:] = copy(a)
  end
end


function foo2()
  historyarray = zeros(5000,150,2)
  a = randn(150,2)
  for i in 1:5000
    pd = pairwise(Euclidean(),a.')
    xgv = broadcast(-,a[:,1].',a[:,1])
    ygv = broadcast(-,a[:,2].',a[:,2])
    th = atan2.(ygv,xgv)
    fv = 1./(pd+1)
    xfv = fv.*cos.(th)
    yfv = fv.*sin.(th)
    a[:,1]+= sum(xfv,2)
    a[:,2]+= sum(yfv,2)

    historyarray[i,:,:] = copy(a)
  end
end

@time foo1()
@time foo2()
```

Console output:

```
29.723805 seconds (2.65 M allocations: 8.566 GB, 1.15% gc time)
16.296859 seconds (2.81 M allocations: 8.571 GB, 2.54% gc time)
```